# CoreData, Data processing in several steps

Tags: core-data, data-migration

I have a large number of text files that i have to process and put the contents into core data. The text files contain a lot of useless information and can contain duplicates for the useful data. So i decided to do the importing in several steps.

First of all, i remove all the useless parts and generate strings with only the useful bits separated by certain separators. Then i put each one of those strings into managed objects first making sure that the storage doesn't contain object with that particular string, thus I make sure each one of them is unique.

Well, i've completed the first step, and now I have to move on, but don't know how to go about it:

I have to split those strings by separators, create corresponding object and save in a different file.

How do i do that?
It stands to reason that i have to create a new datamodel, but how do i save it after the parsing as a separate file?

I thought of doing this as migration from one datamodel version to another, but those text files are generated daily, and it doesn't look like a good idea.

Please give me a hint or direct me to some manual about that. (i am still reading Mr. Zarra's book, haven't found anything of this sort there yet).

Thank you in advance, 
Timofey

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it sounds like you actually need to data models each with a different central entity. First, you process the raw text and produce a string, then you need to convert that string into an actual data object with several attributes. So, lets call the first entity `Preprocessed` and the second `Processed`.

Core Data lets you use multiple data models and even multiple stores in the same managedObjectContext. The key to doing is configurations. Assign each entity to it's own configuration and assign each configuration to it's own store (see the docs for details.) With both entities in the same context, it is easy to move data from one entity to another in a controlled fashion. (Note, you can't form direct relationships between objects in different configurations but everything else, including fetched relationships still work.)

To employ, you would first read the raw text and create you your `Preprocessed` objects. If needed you could do fetches on the `Processed` objects to prevent duplication. Then you have a method to populate a new `Processed` object with the data from the existing `Preprocessed` objects.

When you save, the `Processed` objects go into one persistent store file and the `Preprocessed` into another. You can delete `Preprocessed` without affecting the `Processed` objects and vice versa.